# Unable to upload .torrent with node.js and utorrent-api

Tags: node.js, utorrent

I'm trying to use [utorrent-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utorrent-api) library for `node.js` as in example:

```
request({'uri' : 'http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent', 'encoding': null}, function (error, response, torrentFileBuffer) {
    utorrent.call('add-file', {'torrent_file': torrentFileBuffer}, function(err, data) {
        if(err) { console.log('error : '); console.log(err); return; }

        console.log('Successfully added torrent file !');
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

and I'm getting this error in console:

```
error :
{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
```

I can connect to uTorrent with:

```
utorrent.call('list', function(err, torrents_list) {
    console.log(torrents_list);
});
```

And I'm getting torrents list correctly.
I tried to save .torrent file to disk and it looks ok, so the problem is with file upload.

uTorrent 3.3 is running on Linux. WebUI is working and I can upload .torrent files through browser.
How can I debug this error?